# Conditionally bypass a command based on type of shell bash vs ksh

Tags: bash, ksh

I have this line in script.

```
if [ "$(ps -p $$ -o comm=)" = "bash" ]; then
    exec 1> >(tee -ia $SDIR/bash.log)
fi
```

It only works in bash, but when the shell is not bash, that is in ksh, I get this error

```
./col[2]: 0403-057 Syntax error at line 3 : `>' is not expected.
```

Any way to make the script generic? I want basically to create a output log file of the script if it runs in bash/ksh and also display on screen.

Tried

```
if [ "$(ps -p $$ -o comm=)" = "bash" ]; then
    exec 1> >(tee -ia $SDIR/bash.log)
fi
```

but does not work.

Comment: The problem is probably caused by `ksh` trying to parse the `exec 1> ...` line despite not needing to execute it.  One way to work around the problem is to use `eval` to delay parsing of the command: `eval 'exec 1> >(tee -ia $SDIR/bash.log)'`.  Use of `eval` is generally best avoided (see [Why should eval be avoided in Bash, and what should I use instead?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17529220/4154375)) but this use is safe.

Comment: FWIW, `case $BASH_VERSION in '') echo "The shell is not bash";; *) echo "The current shell is bash";; esac` is cleaner than hackery with `ps`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Any way to make the script generic?

You can get output to both screen and log in both shells, which I guess is even more generic than you asked.  Use a compound command  (`{ ... }`) to wrap everything whose output you want to capture in the log, and pipe its output into `tee`.

Be aware that the use of a pipe will force the compound command into a subshell, which is not analogous to your version.  That could conceivably have unwanted side effects, but I'm inclined to guess that that's unlikely in your particular case.

Example:

```
SDIR=/foo/bar

{
    echo 'Hello, World!'
} | tee -ia "${SDIR}/bash.log"
```

Answer (score 1):

Rather than trying to restrict functionality to certain shells, just write a generic script.  Note that if you do decide to restrict functionality, don't restrict to certain shells.  Instead, test whether the current shell supports the functionality and decide based on that.  Test functionality, not platform.
It's not terribly pretty, but you can get the functionality you want with a fairly generic script.  eg:

```
#!/bin/sh
trap 'rm -f $t' 0 # cleanup the temporary file on exit
t=$(mktemp)       # create the temp file (will be a fifo) 
rm $t; mkfifo $t  # convert the tmpfile to a fifo
tee -ia $SDIR/bash.log < $t & # spawn tee to read the fifo 
exec > $t        # redirect all output to the fifo
echo foo
```

Comment: They're not trying to restrict functionality. They want to use shell-specific extensions when available. But the syntax has to be compatible with all the shells.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy The `exec >&` was a typo; It should just be `exec > $t`  It was certainly not an attempt to redirect both output streams!  Thanks for pointing that out.

Answer (score 0):

Simple way is to check the existence of `$BASH_VERSION` to detect bash. This is not foolproof, but usually what you want to do.

```
if [ -n "$BASH_VERSION" ]; then
```

Also take a look at OpenSUSE distribution /etc/profile implementation, which uses `/proc/self/exe` to determine the executable name https://github.com/openSUSE/aaa_base/blob/master/files/etc/profile#L14 .

Comment: `BASH_VERSION` can be exported, so this doesn't work in general.  The test isn't guaranteed to work even when run by Bash because `BASH_VERSION` can be unset.

Comment: @pjh, true, but anyone who exports `BASH_VERSION` gets what they deserve: it's an explicit operation that any reasonable person can _expect_ to break things.

Comment: This solution doesn't solve the syntax incompatiblity problem. The shell parses everything, even if it's an in a`if` block that's skipped.